# C++ GDAL API: Add more than one rasters to VRT

Tags: gdal, c++, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I want to add more than one tiff file into a vrt file, Well Based on GDAL documentations it is possible to create a vrt using this code

```
GDALDriver *poDriver = (GDALDriver *) GDALGetDriverByName( "VRT" );
GDALDataset *poSrcDS, *poVRTDS;
poSrcDS = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpenShared( "utm.tif", GA_ReadOnly );
poVRTDS = poDriver->CreateCopy( "wrk.vrt", poSrcDS, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL );
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH) poVRTDS);
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH) poSrcDS);
```

but it only adds utm.tif. what If I want to add another set of images into this vrt file? can I use `poDriver->CreateCopy` again and it appends the images into the source vrt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that adding

```
poSrcDS = poDriver->CreateCopy( "wrk.vrt", poSrcDS, FALSE,
                               APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES, NULL, NULL );
```

before closing the datasets should add the second dataset to the VRT as well.

Hope this helps