# stack_raster.cpp:35:99: error: 'YES' was not declared in this scope

Tags: gdal, c++, vrt, append

I've been playing around with C++ and the API for GDAL to create some functions that I have done using Python. One of them was to create a virtual raster based on a list of files found in certain directory. I accomplished the later using the boost library. And when it comes the turn to write the virtual raster, I find that the vrt generated only contains one band. 
I checked some questions regarding this problems, and the most close to my issue is found in the following link:

`https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269976/c-gdal-api-add-more-than-one-rasters-to-vrt`

However when compiling my program using 
`g++ -o stack_raster.exe stack_raster.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lgdal`

I get the following message:

`stack_raster.cpp:35:99: error: 'YES' was not declared in this scope ver->CreateCopy("media/B02_stack.vrt", poSrcDS,RALSE,APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES,NULL,NULL,NULL);`

Before I was having no issues during the compilation by replacing `APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES,NULL,NULL,NULL)`, for `NULL`. The resulted Virtual raster generated only contains one band, as expected. Could someone gives me a hint about my problem?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h" /* for CPLMalloc() */
#include "gdal/vrtdataset.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "gdal/cpl_string.h"
#include <stdbool.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    GDALAllRegister();

    path p("/home/roger/Documents/09_Stack_Raster/media");
    GDALDriver *poDriver = (GDALDriver*) GDALGetDriverByName( "VRT" );
    GDALDataset *poSrcDS, *poVRTDS;
    string bdir = "media/";

    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {   
        string filename = i -> path().filename().string();
        cout << filename << endl;
        if (!is_directory(i->path()) && boost::ends_with(filename, ".tif"))
        {
            cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
            std::string str_path = "media/" + i->path().filename().string();
            poSrcDS = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpenShared(str_path.c_str(), GA_ReadOnly);
            poVRTDS = poDriver->CreateCopy("media/B02_stack.vrt", poSrcDS,FALSE,APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES,NULL,NULL);
            GDALClose((GDALDatasetH) poSrcDS);
        }

        else
            continue;
    }

    GDALClose((GDALDatasetH) poVRTDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that in the line:

```
poVRTDS = poDriver->CreateCopy("media/B02_stack.vrt", poSrcDS,FALSE,APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES,NULL,NULL);
```

you need to place quotes around (at least) APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES:

```
poVRTDS = poDriver->CreateCopy("media/B02_stack.vrt", poSrcDS,FALSE,"APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES",NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: I changed the line to yours and it compiled. I created a char **papszOptions = CSLSetNameVlue(papszOptions, "APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES), and afterwards pass it as variable in CreateCopy, so the next line is ```poVRTDS= poDriver->CreateCopy("media/B02_stack.vrt", poSrcDS, FALSE, papszOptions, NULL, NULL)```, but now I receive the following message: ```Segmentation fault (cored dumped)```

Comment: This sort of programming question is better asked on stack overflow or the gdal user list.